# The returned-value type of Arrays.asList in Java

Tags: java, generic-list

The following line is copied directly from the documentation of the `Arrays.asList()` method:

```
List<String> stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
```

When trying this line in my code, I get the following compilation error:

> The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

My question is *why*?

To be more specific, how can this method return a `List<String>` object if `List` is not generic?

Comment: Have to ask:  Did you accidentally import the non-generic `java.awt.List`?

Comment: I imported what the IDE suggested when I hovered `List`. Are you suggesting that's the problem???

Comment: You should import `java.util.List`.

Comment: Yes. When the IDE suggests two different classes with the same name, it's your responsibility to choose the right one. You should controle the IDE, not vice-versa.

Comment: Yep; I see that now. Thanks a lot! I gotta admit it's a silly question in that case, and I should have been able to detect the problem. But on the other hand, I've never had the IDE suggesting the wrong import, so I guess I would have never thought in that direction... thanks again :)

Comment: P.S.: should probably remove this question before anyone else sees it...

Comment: I've added a Community Wiki answer, that you can accept, and then anybody making a similar mistake in the future should be able to find out how you solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been suggested in the comments, the reason for the error is probably that you've imported the wrong `List`. What you wanted was a `java.util.List` which can take generics, whereas you've probably imported `java.awt.List`, which can't. Changing the import statement to bring in the correct type should solve the problem.